# Draggscroll image in flutter, is possible?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to do something like this on flutter?
[draggscroll](https://donmbelembe.github.io/vue-dragscroll)

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what specific thing you want but you can try using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/zoom_widget